# Dynamic Component Loading - get component as variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I'm implementing a relatively complex [component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) in Angular, and I'd like to dynamically get the component instance from a rxjs store.

```
loadEditAreaComponent(component: any, componentInstanceData?: {}){
    const componentFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    const viewContainerRef = this.editAreaHost.viewContainerRef;
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    Object.keys(componentInstanceData).forEach(key => {
      componentRef.instance[key] = componentInstanceData[key];
})
```

It works. However, I'm feeling `any` is a little sloppy here. I can't seem to find the correct type.

The signature of `resolveComponentFactory` is
`(method) ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory<unknown>(component: Type<unknown>): ComponentFactory<unknown>`.

When I'm saying `component: Type` I'm getting:
`Argument of type 'Type' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<unknown>'.`

When I'm saying `component: Type<unknown>` or `Type<any>` I'm getting:
`Type 'Type' is not generic.`

Would appreciate assistance, and would also love to get some background regarding the Typescript constraints I'm probably failing to understand.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you importing `Type` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of [resolveComponentFactory](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver#resolveComponentFactory) method looks like:

```
abstract resolveComponentFactory<T>(component: Type<T>): ComponentFactory<T>;
```

You should be using the same type:

```
import { Type } from '@angular/core';

loadEditAreaComponent<T>(component: Type<T>, ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that the `Type<unknown>` should have worked, and I probably imported `Type` from the wrong path.